# Finding the time for an epidemic/computer virus to infect a population

Tags: logarithms, computer-science

Question: "Suppose a computer worm makes 2 copies of itself on another computer in one millisecond. Estimate the time that is needed to spread to a population of 1,000,000 computers" How would I calculate time?

I am using a textbook by Goodrich, "Introduction to Computer Security" and they glaze over this in no detail but they do show a logarithmic graph similar to this.

Picture is ONLY for show case what is occurring, it is not numerically tied to the question.

[image]

Comment: That curve is not related to the type of growth in your question.

Comment: The curve you have plotted is logistic-like; this essentially means that the growth is "exponential" for a short time, until some sort of supply limitation effect slows down the growth, and ultimately a finite limit is obtained at infinity. The model you have described has no such supply limitation built in. In fact, the model you have described has an exponential solution exponential: if $n$ viruses exist now, then $3n$ viruses will exist a millisecond from now, so $n(t)=n(0)3^t$ where $t$ is in milliseconds. Now you solve that with a logarithm.

Comment: What is missing in your description of the problem is any discussion of how the two infected computers are chosen. Let us assume that each infected computer is able to infect any other computer (that a complete graph of connections exists). Let us also assume that the infected computer is not able to identify its potential victim as already infected, so it may try to infect a computer that is laready infected. Under those assumptions the logistic-like graph will emerge...

Comment: ... initially growth is approximately proportional to $3^t$ because the number of infected computers wil usually treble (since very unlikely to try to reinfect). Later the chance of trebling will decrease as there are more and more infected computers and finally the rate of infection slows as it is hard to infect the last remaining few uninfected computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the situation at time $t$ where there are $n_i(t)$ infected computers and $n_c(t)$ clean computers. We know that $n_c(t)+n_i(t)=N$, the total number of computers.

The infected computers send out two worms each.

The first worms could infect $n_i(t)$ computers.

But some of the computers that receive worms are already infected. The number of clean computers that receive the worms is approximately $n_i(t)\times \frac {n_c(t)} N$. Therefore the number of clean computers is now $n_c(t)-\frac {n_i(t) n_c(t)} N$.

The second worms could also infect $n_i(t)$ computers.
But the number of clean computers has already decreased and the number of clean computers that receive these worms is $n_i(t) \times \frac {n_c-\frac {n_i(t) n_c(t)} N} N$

That leaves us with $n_c(t)-\frac {n_i(t) n_c(t)} N - n_i(t) \times \frac {n_c-\frac {n_i(t) n_c(t)} N} N$ clean computers.

And the number of infected computers is $N-n_c(t)+\frac {n_i(t) n_c(t)} N + n_i(t) \times \frac {n_c-\frac {n_i(t) n_c(t)} N} N$.

This is $n_i(t)+\frac {n_i(t) (N-n_i(t))} N + n_i(t) \times \frac {N-n_i-\frac {n_i(t) (N-n_i(t))} N} N$

$n_i(t+1)=n_i(t)+n_i(t)-\frac {n^2_i(t)} N + n_i(t)- \frac {n^2_i(t)} N - \frac {n^2_i(t)} N + \frac {n^3_i(t)} {N^2}$

$n_i(t+1)=3n_i(t)-3 \frac {n^2_i(t)} N + \frac {n^3_i(t)} {N^2}$

Putting this into Excel gave me these results:

```
0   1.000
1   3.000
2   9.000
3   27.000
4   80.997
5   242.971
6   728.735
7   2184.611
8   6539.527
9   19490.564
10  57339.450
11  162343.434
12  412242.755
13  796954.218
14  991628.912
15  999999.413
16  1000000.000
```

So about 16 milliseconds...